# SQL Function Result to File

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We've got a longstanding function that writes the results of a query to a file.  This works great.  However, now I'm tasked with writing the result of a function to a file The function returns a dataset based on some input parameters.  When run by itself in a Query window, results are returned in the Result Pane.  But when passed to our "CreateFile" function, a blank file is written (if the return code is trapped).

```
EXECUTE LoanStatusChangeTracking '2011-5-26','2011-5-27','44000'
```

returns 65 rows for today.

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(MAX)
set @Query = 'EXECUTE [BankA].[dbo].[LoanStatusChangeTracking] ''2011-5-26'',''2011-5-27'',''44000'' '
Exec dbo.Ufn_CreateFile @Query, 'Collections2011-5-27.csv', 'S:\FTPTransferDaily', 'lms_user', 'kkoi8333323', '172.25.200.71', default
```

Doesn't return anything or create a file.  I can run it with a simple sql script and results get written.

What would be a likely place to start investigation?

Comment: likely place to start investigation would be the definition of `dbo.Ufn_CreateFile` for me. How does that work?

Comment: Thanks Martin.  ufn_CreateFile works find when passed a simple query.  I've looked into it, and it is a wrapper for the "bcp" command.  I recreated what the CreateFile function was doing, and I still have the issue.  So, how can I get the "bcp" program/command to work when passed a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to temp tables.  They don't last, of course, and by the time the Create File function ran, there wasn't anything to write to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQLCMD - `sqlcmd -i <input_file> -o <output_file>`